# Moving Specific Object in OpenGL C Linux

Tags: c, linux, opengl, glut

I'm having a problem moving an specific object in OpenGL using C.

Object CODE

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1, 0.73, 0.06);
glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
glPushMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glRotatef(0,PacX,PacY,0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(ax, ay);
    glVertex2f(bx, by);
    glVertex2f(cx, cy);
    glVertex2f(dx, dy);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glFlush();
```

This will draw a square, but in the window i have other objects, so when i try to move only the square with glTranslatef() it moves all the objects, is there a way or variable where i can store a pointer or an ID to the square so i can move only the square ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save and restore the transformation matrix for each object, so that each object gets its own matrix.

See the `glPushMatrix()` function.

Comment: but glPushMatrix doens't return any value so how can i store an object value and get it back to move it ?

Comment: @user1343820: OpenGL does not "store objects", it doesn't maintain a scene. It just draws point, lines at triangles. You send drawing commands, OpenGL draws each line, point or triangle individually and forgets about it. If you want to change something, you must redraw the scene.

Comment: to move and object i use glTranslatef(x,y,z) but it moves all objects in the scene, my question is, it is possible to user glTranslatef() to move only one specific object ?

Comment: @user1343820 Have a look at what a `stack` is and how the OpenGL machinery uses one to keep track of which transformations to do for the current rendering. If you need different translations for different parts, you need to push the current matrix, do the needed changes, render and then pop the stack to get the old matrix and render the rest.

Comment: Just keep the location of the object within the object and call glTranslate() where you call 'glRotatef(0,PacX,PacY,0);'. That is how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Read about OpenGL display lists, and allocate a display list in the graphics card.  From the OpenGL Programming Guide

```
/* Create display list with Torus and initialize state*/
static void init(void)
{
   theTorus = glGenLists (1);
   glNewList(theTorus, GL_COMPILE);
   torus(8, 25);
   glEndList();

   glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

where `torus(8, 25)` calls a function that draws the elements that are captured into `theTorus` by the surrounding `glNewList(...)` and `glEndList()` functions.  Then your drawing looks more like

```
void display(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   glCallList(theTorus);
   glFlush();
}
```

which means that you can alter the environment prior to drawing the torus by calling various `glRotatef(...)` and other scaling and transformation calls.

The entire example I've been pulling references from [can be accessed here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter07.html).

With a few additional data structures, you can hold the orientation of the object in a struct, apply the transforms to the environment, and then draw the particular display list.  Don't remember to un-apply the transformation of the environment afterwards, and then you will have effectively rotated, moved, or did whatever to the single object represented in the display list.

Comment: @HugoGonçalves I am glad to hear it.